# How to create an array in R with the vector elements row wise?

Tags: r, arrays

When I create an array it always stores the elements column wise I've searched for row-wise but can't find anything
For example for this code

```
  X = c(1,2,3)
  Y = c(4,5,6,7,8,9)
  R = array(c(X,Y), dim=c(3,3,2))
  print(R)
```

How do I get an output of

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
aperm(R, c(2, 1, 3))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```